# iBooks automatically generating cover pages for PDFs?

Tags: ipad, ios, books

I've loaded some lengthy PDFs onto my iPad in iBooks, and I've noticed that for only one of them, it's seemed to have created a beige cover page for the PDF thumbnail with what looks like the file name. It's nice, but I was unaware of this feature and ideally I'd like it to include the author and paper title instead of the file name. Does anyone know more about this functionality or how I can change what this new cover page says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the PDF in Preview on a Mac, you can drag/drop page thumbnails around (hold option to copy a page) and even drag a page from one PDF into another.

This way you can use the print system's "Save as PDF" feature to set anything as the first page.

Alternatively switch from bookshelf view to list view, where you can see the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the thumbnail is created from the first page in the pdf document.

So to alter the icon you could add another coverpage to the pdf document.